# Centos 7 Puppet Enterprise installation - Connection refused on 4433 port

Tags: centos, puppet, firewall, puppet-enterprise

Installation of Puppet Enterprise on Centos 7 is failing due to the following error:

"2017-06-21 07:11:41,242 - [Error]: Failed to apply catalog: Connection refused - connect(2) for "abc.xyz.com" port 4433"

I have done the following steps:

1. Install firewalld: yum install firewalld
2. Start firewalld service: sudo systemctl start firewalld.service
3. Get firewall zones: firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
   --> This did not return anything
4. Add port 4433 to public zone:

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=4433/tcp --permanent
--> This did returned "success" message

5. Reload : firewall-cmd --reload
6. Search of 4433 port: netstat -tulpn | grep 4433
   --> This did not return anything
7. Check port 4433: curl -v abc.xyz.com:4433
   --> This still return " Connection refused" error.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I faced was when I was trying to install using the web console "https://abc.xyz.com:3000". The issue was resolved by using pe.conf file for the installation.

```
{
  "console_admin_password": "password",
  "puppet_enterprise::puppet_master_host": "abc.xyz.com",
  "pe_install::puppet_master_dnsaltnames": [
    "puppet",
    "master",
    "abc"
  ],
  "puppet_enterprise::use_application_services": true
}
```